# Foundation6 centered dropdown pane

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation, dropdown

I am building a new page with a lot of tooltips. The tooltips in this page should contain HTML contents. So I have to use the dropdown pane, right?

**Question**

I couldn't find a way to top-center it above the triggering element like the "real" tooltip. I've tried the data-v-offset attribute, which works like a charm and the data-h-offset attribute which won't have any effect. Could somebody please help me?

**Additional question to make it more special ;-)**

Also it would be great to prevent the direction change. So fe my dropdown is aligned top, but if i scroll down, it will be shown below the link instead of above. But like the "real tooltip" I need to show a centered corner on the bottom, pointing to the trigger. So I can not change direction as the corner / arrow would otherwise be pointing in a wrong direction.

I am really looking forward hearing from you. Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered or used [Foundation 6 Tooltip](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/tooltip.html) Feature ?

Comment: I didn't try, why should I, do I miss something? It's a fact that F6 Tooltips cant hold html content (like additional rows and columns, images, buttons,...) :)

Comment: I haven't tried F6 Tooltip but I felt it was right on to your purpose. I didn't know F6 can't hold html. Anyway, if you are still interested in using html with it, then this thread might be helpful : http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/38057-tooltip-foundation-6-does-not-accept-html-tags